# Runtime error wen using Hamcrest Matchers in Android production code with proguard

Tags: java, android, validation, proguard, hamcrest

I am writing an app that has a form with text fields that take numbers. To check whether the input is valid I decided to use Hamcrest Matchers. I defined:

```
public static <T> boolean checkThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher) {
    return matcher.matches(actual);
}
```

such that I can use stuff like:

```
if(checkThat(doubleFromText,greaterThan(0.0)) doSomething();
```

Now this works perfectly fine in debug mode, but when I enable proguard for production release the application crashes immediately with the following message (obtained with retrace):

```
java.lang.Error: Cannot determine correct type for matchesSafely() method.
        at org.hamcrest.internal.ReflectiveTypeFinder.findExpectedType(Unknown Source)
                                                      canObtainExpectedTypeFrom
        at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hamcrest.number.OrderingComparison.greaterThan(Unknown Source)
                                                  matchesSafely
        at org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix this?

I made a minimal example demonstrating the problem: https://github.com/burgerga/HamcrestMatchersWithProguard

---

**Notes:**

- I added `-dontwarn java.beans.**` to my proguard rules to get it to compile.
- Before you start telling me I should just use `if(doubleFromText > 0)`, the example I gave was simplified. In my code I use something like

  ```
  checkThat(textIn(myEditText),parsesToDouble(greaterThan(0.0)));
  ```

  where `parsesToDouble` is a simple matcher I wrote. I think this is a very flexible and clear way to state my intent, and I'm simply interested in how to get it working with proguard.

Answer (score 5):

Because Hamcrest uses reflection, some methods get deleted in the shrinking phase that shouldn't be deleted. I was able to get it working again by adding

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class org.hamcrest.number.** { *** matchesSafely(...); }
```

to the proguard rules. If you don't care about a slightly larger apk you can add

```
-keep class org.hamcrest.** { *; }
```

to make sure nothing from hamcrest gets deleted.